# Autocomplete in CodeIgniter MySQL with JQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I found a problem regarding autocomplete in codeigniter, i want to make if I fill siteid with *autocomplete*, in another form (sitename) will show data from database directly, but i failed, autocomplete form in siteid not shown, so another field can't worked too

**Here my controller code :**

```
    public function get_allkota() {
    $kode = $this->input->post('kode',TRUE); 
    $query = $this->db->get("tbl_site");

    $kota       =  array();
    foreach ($query as $d) {
        $kota[]     = array(
            'label' => $d->siteid,
            'nama' => $d->siteid ,
            'sitename' => $d->sitename,
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($kota);   
}
```

**Here my jquery code :**

```
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(function () {
    $("#kode").autocomplete({  
        minLength:0,
        delay:0,
        source:'<?php echo site_url('app_admin_kabupaten/get_allkota'); ?>', 
        select:function(event, ui){
            $('#siteid').val(ui.item.siteid);
            $('#sitename').val(ui.item.sitename);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here my form code :**

```
<p><input type="text" id="kode" placeholder="Fill site ID" > </p>
<p>Site ID : </br><input type="text" id="siteid"></br>
   Site Name : </br><input type="text" id="sitename"></br>
```

thanks

Comment: "I found a problem regarding autocomplete in codeigniter"... So what is the problem?

Comment: @DamithRuwan i was edit it, i can't run autocomplete data, if you any suggestion, please advise, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your controller code, when you do `$this->db->get('table_name')`, codeigniter returns query object. You need to fetch the results from it.

from documentation:

```
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->field;
}
```

So change your controller code to this and it should work,

```
public function get_allkota() {
    $kode = $this->input->get('term'); 

    $this->db->like('siteid', $kode); 
    $query = $this->db->get("tbl_site");
    $kota       =  array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $d) {
        $kota[]     = array(
            'label' => $d->siteid,
            'nama' => $d->siteid ,
            'sitename' => $d->sitename,
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($kota);   
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, i change into foreach ($query->result() as $row){echo $row->sitename;echo $row->siteid;}, may you give in full edit?

Comment: have you tried the `get_allkota()` function that i have included in my answer?

Comment: i think your get_allkota() same with my controller before,

Comment: no. That's what i said in my answer. you looped the `$query` object. you need to loop `$query->results()` which contains the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147128/discussion-between-karisma-and-sayantan-das).

Answer (score 0):

```
// js code after document is ready
// Search autocomplete
$("#swSearch").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(req, add){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/search', //Controller where search is performed
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: req,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.response =='true'){
                   add(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

// Controller search function


    $keyword = $this->input->post('term');

    $data['response'] = 'false'; //Set default response

    $query = $this->Mprofile->sw_search($keyword); //Model DB search

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
       $data['response'] = 'true'; //Set response
       $data['message'] = array(); //Create array
       foreach($query->result() as $row){
          $data['message'][] = array('label'=> $row->friendly_name, 'value'=> $row->friendly_name); //Add a row to array
       }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

// Simple model example

public function sw_search($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->select('id, friendly_name');
        $this->db->from('business_category');
        $this->db->where('suppress', 0);
        $this->db->like('friendly_name', $keyword);
        $this->db->order_by("friendly_name", "asc");

        $query = $this->db->get();
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
            //$data[$row['friendly_name']];
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        //return $data;
        return $query;
    }

Enjoy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In core PHP here is the code

///////////////////////Search.php////////////////

    <?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = '';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = '';
//connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
//get matched data from skills table
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' group by column_name ORDER BY column_name ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['column_name'];
}
//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>


///////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////Index.php///////////////////

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search.php'
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="skills">Skills: </label>
  <input id="skills">
</div>
</body>
</html>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```